# My bike keeps making this grinding noise around the back wheel/casette/chainring area when I get speed on a tech/ jump trail

Tags: mountain-bike, chainring, specialized-bikes, skipping

It is an older bike that hasn't been used in years and I recently got it serviced and began using it on the trails.  It is a specialized stumpjumper from around the 2004/2005 era and everything seems to be running smoothely except for the noise.

Comment: Could we get a video?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You could help get a better answer by supplying more details, like is the noise constant, does it have a period synchronized to the wheel, does it only happen when pedaling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are **many...many potential root cause** for the noise.

**Firstly**, you mentioned that you had it *serviced*. It could be good if you describe ***what kind of service it entails***? 
Many a times, *shops claim full service but it's just a wipe down*. (in my country)

If the service is complete, there shouldn't be any noise right?
*Let's assume from here that the service is a wipe down*.

**Secondly**, the ***drivetrain***.
Was the **cassette** installed properly? - If not, the cogs may not be fully engaged in the freehub body and cause some slippage.
Was the **chainring** installed properly? - At speeds, a little anti-squat can cause your chainring to rattle.
Is the **chain** too long? - Exacerbates the anti-squat effect. + of course chain slap.
Is the **derailleur** properly indexed? - If not, at jumps, the chain might be forced to shift or rub against the next cogs excessively.

**Thirdly**, the ***wheels***.
Is it only **freewheeling** that you hear the noise? Or does it happen at high speed **pedalling** too?
Is the **tyre bead** seated properly in the rim bed?
What's the **lacing pattern on your wheels**? - could it be that the spokes are rubbing under constant fluctuations in tension at speeds?

**Lastly**, the ***bottom bracket***.
Is it **installed incorrectly**? - This is the least likely root cause, as it'll cause problems regardless of speeds.

Hope you understand that like doctors, just because it hurts, doesn't mean the doctors know what syndrome you have. I believe that more information is needed. :)

*Also, I didn't even mention the rear shock (I'm guessing there's one). By itself, it requires so much TLC, and that's a whole new topic already.*

Comment: also disc brakes (if fitted) can make a variety of noises from a clean musical note to a nasty grindign

Comment: the tire may also be rubbing on the stays by just a hair